# Why does sed remove the character in the example?

Tags: sed, replace

```
a=a
b=ab
c=''
d=''
echo ac | sed "s/$a/$b/;"
abc
echo ac | sed "s/$a/$b/; s/$c/$d/"
bc
```

Why does sed remove the character 'a' in the last example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happens because the `$c` is an empty string, and when `sed` is passed the subsequent `s` command with an empty pattern, the previous one is used, in this case, `$a`, which is `a`.

So,

```
echo ac | \ 
 sed "s/$a/$b/; s/$c/$d/"
#       a  ab     a
```

Here,

- `a` is replaced with `ab` first with `s/a/ab/` (`ac` turns into `abc`)
- `a` is removed with `s/a//` (`abc` is turned into `bc`).

See documentation, the [*Regular Expressions in sed* section](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/sed.html#tag_20_116_13_02):

> If an RE is empty (that is, no pattern is specified) *sed* shall behave as if the last RE used in the last command applied (either as an address or as part of a substitute command) was specified.